# Generating unique urls to submitted pictures?

Tags: javascript, html, url, unique

**[Here](http://www.ewsprojects.com/~lyons)** is the site.

As you can see, I have individual submitted pictures that can be viewed by clicking on the thumbnail. It's all done through JS. How do I make it so that when someone submits a picture, a new page with a unique url is created to just that image?

Thanks in advance. Please let me know if there is any code you need from me. :)

Comment: Where is the site? And what are you using on the server side, that's what matters.

Comment: What is this, another [imgur](http://imgur.com) clone?

Answer (score 1):

You could change each name to a random file name. (assuming you already have written the image to a file using the `$imagefilename` variable, and the extension is .jpg)

```
<?php
   //The image, defined as $image
   //Write the image to a file, using the $imagefilename variable for a name.
   $webpagefilename = rand();
   $imagefilename = $webpagefilename.".jpg";
   $myFile = $filename.".html";
   $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("Error: Can't open file");
   $stringData = "<img src='".$imagefilename."' />";
   fwrite($fh, $stringData);
   fclose($fh);
?>
```

Try that. :P